# how to create an autocomplete textbox in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

Hi i am developing a plugin in wordpress.

i tried code for create autocomplete text box in my customized form.

**Ajax Calling function**

```
function city_action_callback() {     
    global $wpdb;
    $city=$_GET['city'];
    $result =   $mytables=$wpdb->get_results("select * from ".$wpdb->prefix . "mycity where city like '%".$city."'" );   
    $data = "";
    foreach($result as $dis)
        {
            $data.=$dis->city."<br>";
        }    
    echo $data;
    die();
    }
add_action( 'wp_ajax_city_action', 'city_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_city_action', 'city_action_callback' );
```

**Shortcode function**

```
function my_search_form()  {
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery('#city').keyup(function() { 
                cid=jQuery(this).attr('val');
                var ajaxurl="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>"; 
                var data ={ action: "city_action",  city:cid    };
                $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response){
                          //alert(response);
                        });
                });
});
</script>

 <input type="text" id="city"  name="city" autocomplete="off"/>

<?php
}
```

this code return related results perfectly in variable response.

But i don't know how create a text box look like a autocomplete box.

Please explain me how to do that in wordpress?

Comment: refer this http://tutsforweb.blogspot.in/2012/05/auto-complete-text-box-with-php-jquery.html

Comment: @cracker its core php code. I don't know how to implement in wordpress plugin

Comment: @Boopathi you can use corephp code in wordpress...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a div under the input tag

**HTML Code:**

`<input type="text" id="city"  name="city" autocomplete="off"/>
<div id="key"></div>`

replace the div after the success on you ajax.

**Ajax Code:**

```
            var ajaxurl="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>"; 
            var data ={ action: "city_action",  city:cid    };
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response){
                     $('#key').html(response);
                    });
```

**PHP Code:**

```
            function city_action_callback() {     
            global $wpdb;
            $city=$_GET['city'];
            $result =   $mytables=$wpdb->get_results("select * from ".$wpdb->prefix . "mycity where city like '%".$city."'" );   
            $data = "";
            echo '<ul>'
            foreach($result as $dis)
            {
              echo '<li>'.$dis->city.'</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>'    
            die();
            }
```

Comment: ok thanks. if i Choose any one from list it set to text box. how to do that?

Comment: it depends on the value you need to set to text box. If you already know the value the then in you php code do a validation like the below
if($dis->city == "Yourdesiredcity")
{
  echo $dis->city;
}
Ajax on success
 $('#textboxid').val(response);

Comment: No manoj. if i select anyone value from <li> then this value will be placed to textbox.

Comment: You can use core php codes to wordpress. Its not an issue

Comment: Yes you can do that
foreach($result as $dis)
            {
              echo '<li><a onclick ='getval(this.id)' value='.$dis->city.'>'.$dis->city.'</a></li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>'    
on your script
   function getval(value) { $('#textboxid').val(value)}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58852/discussion-between-boopathi-and-manoj-trivand).